# In Eclipse AVD I get a "Unfortunately, Calculator has stopped." API level 16

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

My test application is called Calculator, but I get an "Unfortunately, Calculator has stopped." error in AVD. I'm running my Android Virtual Device with API Level 16. This is my code : (No syntax errors as far as Eclipse says)

```
MainActivity.java :

    package com.papps.calculator;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int num1 = 90;
    int num2 = 90;
    int op = 0;
    int ans = 0;

    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    Button ButtonEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonEquals);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    //ONE
    public void none() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 1;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 1;
         }
    }
    //TWO
    public void ntwo() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 2;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 2;
         }
    }
    //THREE
    public void nthree() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 3;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 3;
         }
    }
    //FOUR
    public void nfour() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 4;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 4;
         }
    }
    //FIVE
    public void nfive() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 5;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 5;
         }
    }
    //SIX
    public void nsix() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 6;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 6;
         }
    }
    //SEVEN
    public void nseven() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 7;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 7;
         }
    }
    //EIGHT
    public void neight() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 8;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 8;
         }
    }
    //NINE
    public void nnine() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 9;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 9;
         }
    }
    //ZERO
    public void nzero() {
        if(num1 == 90) {
            num1 = 0;
        }
        else if(num2 == 90) {
            num2 = 0;
         }
    }
    //operators

    //MULTIPLY
    public void multiply() {
        op = 1;
    }
    //Divide
    public void divide() {
        op = 2;
    }
    //Add
    public void add() {
        op = 3;
    }
    //Subtract
    public void subtract() {
        op = 4;
    }

    //EQUALS
    //TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    //Button ButtonEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonEquals);
    public void equals() {
        if(op == 1){
            answer.setText(num1 * num2);
        }
        else if(op == 2) {
            answer.setText(num1 / num2);
        }
        else if(op == 3) {
            answer.setText(num1 + num2);
        }
        else if(op == 4) {
            answer.setText(num1 - num2);
        }
    }
    }

activity_main.xml :


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="97dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:onClick = "none" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:onClick = "ntwo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button2"
        android:text="3"
        android:onClick = "nthree" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:onClick = "nfour" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button2"
        android:text="5"
        android:onClick = "nfive" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button3"
        android:text="6" 
        android:onClick = "nsix" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="7" 
        android:onClick = "nseven" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button3"
        android:text="8" 
        android:onClick = "neight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button6"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="9"
        android:onClick = "nnine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button8"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:onClick = "nzero" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="X"
        android:onClick = "multiply" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button7"
        android:text="/"
        android:onClick = "divide" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick = "subtract" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonS"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick = "add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ButtonD"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonD"
        android:text="Answer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonEquals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button0"
        android:text="="
        android:onClick = "equals" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated! I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: post the stack trace from the `LogCat` window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem most likely lies with the global View variables.
Modify

```
TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    Button ButtonEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonEquals);
```

so it is just

```
TextView answer;
Button ButtonEquals;
```

Then in `onCreate()`, do this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    ButtonEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonEquals);
    }
```

Your app is probably crashing because of the fact that you are trying to access the Views before the Activity has anything to show. Putting your code after setContentView allows the Views to be found and you avoid `NullPointerException`s

**Also:**

Your methods need to be `methodName (View view)` if they are referenced from the `onClick:` attribute

Most your methods need to be changed, but I'll take the `ButtonEquals` as an example.
Your xml says

```
android:onClick = "equals"
```

So the method in your code needs to be

```
public void equals (View v)
```

Adding the `View` argument needs to be done for **every** method that the `onClick:` attribute uses.

Answer (score 0):

1/ You can see exactly what's wrong by reading the [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html). It can be seen from Eclipse from the Java perspective or by using the command line:

```
adb logcat
```

2/ Move the instantiation of the *TextView*s to the *onCreate()* method after the *setContentView()* call.

Comment: You can also see the logcat by opening the logcat view in the Java perspective.